# 18.04 Live DVD intallation fails as partitions are not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Trying to install 18.04 (dual boot) on a new Dell Vostro 3670 with a 250gb ssd drive. After resizing the windows partition, I managed to boot from the 18.04 dvd and start the installation. However, after the first few installation screens I get the message "Installation requires 8,6GB You have 0B" and the only option is to exit the installation.

I can guess that the primary win10 partition cannot be detected due to stupid Win10 hibernation features for fast boot. Any ideas why the unallocated part of the disk is not detectable ??

Answer (score 0):

To install Ubuntu you have to disable secure boot from bios and fast boot from windows.

1. In BIOS

   Go to **Boot Manager** in bios and disable the option **Secure Boot**. [Source](https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1811)
2. In Windows

   Search for and open **“Power options”** in the **Start Menu**.

   Click **“Choose what the power buttons do”** on the left side of the window.

   Click **“Change settings that are currently unavailable.”**
   Under **“Shutdown settings”** make sure **“Turn on fast startup”** is enabled.  [Source](https://lifehacker.com/enable-this-setting-to-make-windows-10-boot-up-faster-1743697169)

Comment: have to disable secure boot from bios:   DID THAT

disable fast boot from windows:   I WILL TRY TO FIGURE THIS OUT 

THX A LOT

Comment: @Georgios Tsapogas see edited answer.

Comment: Did you mean to say "make sure **"Turn on fast startup"** is _disabled_?" — it seems that you are telling us to disable, not enable the feature, right?